# python nose don't change working directory path

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I am having an issue with nose. 
I want to run tests in a tests directory but I don't want nose to change the working directory. This is because I am using relative imports in my library and the unittests themselves.

First the directory structure:

```
app_dir
    app.py
    library_dir
        tests_dir
            test_1.py
            test_2.py
```

I am currently running my tests like this from within the `app_dir` directory:

`python -m unittest discover -s library_dir.tests_dir`

This works fine.

Now, I would like to do this with nose (nosetests).

When I try it, I get the following:

```
nosetests library_dir.tests_dir --collect-only -vv
Failure: SystemError (Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import) ... ok
Failure: SystemError (Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import) ... ok
```

I've looked at similar questions on SO already (there are many) and one suggestion for this issue that I can see is to remove the relative imports from within the unittest itself but I like this pattern. Additionally, if I do change to an absolute import, I get an

`(No module named '<the_module_under_test')`

Is there any way for nose to find tests from a directory (like what the `-w` option provides **BUT** keeping the working directory the same as that from the terminal which invoked nose?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, looks like all I needed to do was to add `__init__.py` to the library and the subdirectory tests directory. I was working off of the assumption nose would work as expected with PEP 420

> Blockquote
>   PEP 420: Implicit Namespace Packages

Native support for package directories that don’t require **init**.py marker files and can automatically span multiple path segments (inspired by various third party approaches to namespace packages, as described in PEP 420)